# Android: replace sound of onclick

Tags: android, onclick, android-mediaplayer

I have this code:

```
Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

 }
});
```

when I push my button (in Android 4.0.3) I ear a basic sound (a simply click); Can I replace it with a personal sound? Or I can use only MediaPlayer to play a costum sound?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public MyActivity(Bundle onSavedStateInstance) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mamacita_zero);

    Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
    zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Use SoundPool, not MediaPlayer

Answer (score -1):

You can add sound to your raw folder, initialize it

```
MediaPlayer mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.slow);
```

and call it where ever required

```
    mpSplash.start();
```