# Disable onClick sound for a View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm using a LinearLayout (with some views inside) for representing the sound On/Off button in the Settings screen.

When I set the OnClickListener to this Layout it automatically plays the system "onClick" sound when clicked.

I'd like to play the sound only when the sound is going from 'NoSound' to 'Sound'. How can I supress the sound in the other case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `setSoundEffectsEnabled(false/true);` which should work as per documentation that

> Boolean that controls whether a view should have sound effects enabled
>   for events such as clicking and touching.

Comment: Thanks it is enought for my current problem but do you know how could replace the sound rather than disable it?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142541/android-replace-sound-of-onclick